# VS Win32 program Menu Access keys aren't working when the program is running

Tags: c++, winapi, menu, visual-studio-2013

For some odd reason, the menu access keys appear to be working in the resource editor view but not in the actual program. For example, "&File" underlines the 'F' char in the word "File" while in the resource view but it doesn't in the program and the 'F' key does not access the Menu. I've been trying to fix this for too long so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Accelerators are (depending on your system settings) hidden by default but they should be revealed when you press the Alt key. Do you have any other UI elements that have the same accelerator defined? Or you haven't used `RegisterHotkey` or something like that?

Comment: I knew it was something simple! I had no idea they were hidden by default, so whenever I ran the program I just immediately assumed they weren't working. You're right, after actually pressing the Alt key the access keys were revealed. Thank you so much for your help because that was driving me crazy!

Comment: Some background on this here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/10/05/792913.aspx